# FakeBackendProvider blocking http request in Angular 2 (Observables won't work)

Tags: angular, http, angular2-observables

I have a problem building an app in Angular2.
I try to put an authentication service with the tutorial from [JasonWatsMore](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial).

My problem is: when i make an observable with a classical HTTP request like this one:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
import {Olders} from '../_models/index'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'

@Injectable ()

export class OldersService {

  constructor(private _http:Http) {

  }

  getOldersfromAPI(){
    return this._http.get('/app/ressources/jsons/clients.json')
      .do(x => console.log(x))
       .map(olders => {return olders = olders.json()});
  }
}
```

in a component like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'

import {Olders} from '../_models/index'
import {OldersService} from '../_services/index'



@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'yearbook',
  templateUrl: 'yearbook.component.html',

})

export class YearbookComponent implements OnInit {

  olders : Olders[];

  constructor(
    private _oldersService : OldersService
  ){}


  ngOnInit() {

        this._oldersService.getOldersfromAPI()
            .subscribe( res => {this.olders = res,
              console.log(this.olders)},
              err => console.error(err.status)
              );
  }
}
```

The console don't show anything (it should show me my .json with the .do), and the network activity doesn't show that i'm trying to load something (it should show the .json)

It works well when i take off the identification and the fakeBackendProvider from the providers on the app.module.ts

I assume the http method isn't working with this fakebackend but I don't know how to use this method instead of http to get my json...

Here is the fakeBackendProvider

```
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod 
} from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';

export function fakeBackendFactory(backend: MockBackend, options: 
BaseRequestOptions) {
    // configure fake backend
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        let testUser = { username: 'test', password: 'test', firstName: 
'Test', lastName: 'User' };

    // wrap in timeout to simulate server api call
    setTimeout(() => {

        // fake authenticate api end point
        if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate') && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Post) {
            // get parameters from post request
            let params = JSON.parse(connection.request.getBody());

            // check user credentials and return fake jwt token if valid
            if (params.username === testUser.username && params.password === testUser.password) {
                connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                    new ResponseOptions({ status: 200, body: { token: 'fake-jwt-token' } })
                ));
            } else {
                connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                    new ResponseOptions({ status: 200 })
                ));
            }
        }

        // fake users api end point
        if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/users') && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Get) {
            // check for fake auth token in header and return test users if valid, this security is implemented server side
            // in a real application
            if (connection.request.headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token') {
                connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                    new ResponseOptions({ status: 200, body: [testUser] })
                ));
            } else {
                // return 401 not authorised if token is null or invalid
                connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                    new ResponseOptions({ status: 401 })
                ));
            }
        }

    }, 500);

});

return new Http(backend, options);
}

export let fakeBackendProvider = {
    // use fake backend in place of Http service for backend-less development
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: fakeBackendFactory,
    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
};
```

I tried to reproduce the error with a Plunker but it won't work well.
here it is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3riZcjoVyjztGxfYhVIm)

Comment: `'.../app/ressources/jsons/clients.json'` isn't one of the endpoints handled by the fake backend. It only responds to POSTs to `'.../api/authenticate'` and GETs to `'.../api/users'`. Why are you using a fake backend at all, don't you have an actual API to connect to?

Comment: the tutorial use a fake backend, and i'm coding the front-end of the project for the moment, so I don't have an API to connect to for the authentication for the moment... I should add an endpoint for every file that I want to get ? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Then yes, you'll need to add your own endpoints to the fake backend, otherwise they'll never get a response.

Comment: Ok thanxs i will try

Comment: All my jsons are stored in the same folder. Can i make an option (If) that let the http provide all the jsons stored here ? @jonrsharpe

Comment: I try to add `if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/olders.json')){
              // get parameters from post request
              let params = JSON.parse(connection.request.getBody());
              connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                  new ResponseOptions({ status: 200, body: 'app/ressources/jsons/olders.json' })
              ));
            }` In the setTimeout but it doesn't work...

Comment: Then the body will be *literally that string*, not the file content. If you want to do it that way you'll need to read the file content; you should research on how best to read that data in.

Comment: Yes, but even with the code `if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/olders.json')){
              // get parameters from post request
              let params = JSON.parse(connection.request.getBody());
              connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                    new ResponseOptions({status: 200, body: {name: 'Jeff' }})
              ));
            }` I end up with an error in my [console](https://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/536817Capturedecran20170501a132456.png)